# Latex: Tabbing environment not working within fancyhdr footer and usage of longtabu

Tags: longtable, tabbing

I have problems when I try to use the tabbing environment within a fancyhdr footer and using a longtabu table within the document.

The error message is:
`! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position.`

I tried to use `\linebreak`, `\newline` and `\let\ORInewline\\` but without success.

What should I do?

Here is my code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{
    \begin{tabbing}
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\=bbbbbbbbb\\
        ccccc\>dddddddddddddddddd\\
    \end{tabbing}
}

\begin{longtabu} to 3cm {|X|X|}
    A\vspace{40cm} & B \\ % vspace needed to create table bigger than one page
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

use a `tabular` instead of a `tabbing` environment:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbb\\
        ccccc & dddddddddddddddddd\\
    \end{tabular}%
}
```

However, using `longtable` makes more sense, because `tabu` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

The output routine redefined by `tabu` seems to conflict with the workings of `tabbing`. You can use an indirect method:

```
\newsavebox{\footbox}
\sbox{\footbox}{% <-- Look out for spaces
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\=bbbbbbbbb\\
  ccccc\>dddddddddddddddddd\\
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}% <-- Look out for spaces
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\usebox{\footbox}}
```

This is clearly a bug of `tabu`, but the author has announced he won't look at bug reports for the current version.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in `tabu`.

`tabu` makes many changes to LaTeX commands and does not restore them in the output routine, so things go wrong in headers and footers.

Here it patches `trivlist` (so more or less all LaTeX display environments, including `tabbing`) adding 
`\tabu@normalcrbackslash` to its definition.

So locally within the footer you need to redefine this command to do nothing so that normal behaviour is restored.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\let\tabu@normalcrbackslash\relax
        \begin{tabbing}
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\=bbbbbbbbb\\
        ccccc\>dddddddddddddddddd\\
    \end{tabbing}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{longtabu} to 3cm {|X|X|}
    A\vspace{40cm} & B \\ % vspace needed to create table bigger than one page
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```